# Measurability and composition of functions

Tags: measure-theory

If $f\circ p=h$ and $p:S^m \rightarrow S$ the $i{\text{th}}$ projection ($S$ measurable space) and $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ any function whatsoever ($\mathbb{R}$=reals) and $h$ measurable, is there any condition that makes $f$ measurable?

Comment: If $m=1$ then $p$ is the identity function and $f=h$ guarantees measurability.